# pub/sub in google cloud platform

Tags: java, message-queue, google-cloud-pubsub

How can i view the messages in the queue of pub/sub in google cloud platform?
I have searched for it a lot but, i did not get the related content [Click Here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://linuxacademy.com/community/posts/show/topic/24575-viewing-messages-published-to-a-topic-in-google-pubsub&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1542966091621000&usg=AFQjCNHyIRr3Q2lNAPcba_WhcHCpw9QMdw) I have gone through this link but it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Officially, there are no dashboards to view the message content inside the queue however we can see the number of undelivered messages and the number of published messages which resides into the queue using [StackDriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) Monitoring Dashboard.

However if want to see the message content of the messages present in the queue you can use `gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --auto-ack MySub`.The message you sent appears in the DATA field of the command output.This command acknowledges the message and hence the message will be deleted form the queue.

The hack to prevent the deletion of the messages is to write a script which reads the content of the messages without sending the acknowledgment.